# Flutter Mobile App - Suggestions for best approach on how to include simple animation with sound

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, audio

I am building a mobile reading app (in flutter for IOS and Android) that allows English native kids to read Chinese. It will have kids' books which are in Mandarin/ Simplified Chinese Characters (and parents can toggle on/off additional subtitles in Pinyin and English).
The books will support audio that reads aloud the Simplified Chinese Characters to the children. I want to synchronise this audio with the Chinese Characters and highlight the words one-by-one as they are read aloud.

I am having trouble defining the best approach. I contemplate making individual videos in Adobe Animate that will include the audio which is synchronised with the highlighting of the Chinese Characters. It just does not seem like a good solution to play a mini video at each page for each sentence.

Is there a better way to animate the highlighting of the words and synchronise them with the audio as the children go through the pages of the book?

Thank you for all your suggestions.

I considered using the flutter animation packages to highlight words, but the tempo cannot be manually adjusted and I need something that can synchronise with the words spoken in the audio. Also created mini-video's in Adobe Animate that automatically play when you turn the page, but this is ugly and data heavy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to work with files in lrc format. In a lrc file is stored, when exactly what is said.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_(file_format)

There is already a package to handle this kind of files:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lyric

Basically, you are building something similar to a karaoke app that also uses this file format.